# Create a shell with a different PATH

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

I want to write a script that will create a new shell that has a different path variable *upon instantiation*. That is, I do not want to have to run a configuration script each time I start the new script. I just want the initialization of the shell to have a new [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)). How can I do this?

In terms of specifics, I will be running several tests that require using a modified version of a default package. I want to run these tests from within a new shell, to avoid changing the default `PATH` variable.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a new session for the same machine  or different machine ?

Comment: A new session on the same machine. I was envisioning it going like this:

$ ./new_shell

(new_shell) $  ./tests

Comment: Create a script which calls another script and parameterize the  paths for the new session.So, when you call them, new session is instantiated with new paths. So, idea is call a script using the main wrapper script.

Comment: Yes, that is the goal. I don't know how to parameterize the path, however. I know how to use arguments in a BASH script, I just don't know how to set the PATH of the new shell using those parameters. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're running on Linux/Mac,
you can use it like this:

```
path='something_new' run_command
```

where run_command is your test script.
Run :

```
path='something_new' set | grep path
```

for Mac or :

```
path='something_new' env | grep path
```

for Linux

to ensure it works for you.

Comment: Your two `grep` examples are problematic. The choice of `set` or `env` is not one of operating system. The two commands do different things. `env` is an external binary which will show environment variables. When run from a POSIX-style shell like `/bin/sh or `bash` it will show things that were `export`ed. When run from `tcsh`, it will show things that were set with `setenv`. The `set` command behaves QUITE differently in tcsh than it does in POSIX, and you can run any shell you like in Mac, Linux, FreeBSD, AIX, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> `Script1.sh :`

```
export var1="\user\windows"
export var2="\windows\put"

$var1/Script2.sh "\user\abc\def" "\win\user\class"
```

> `Script2.sh :`

```
export path1=$1
export path2=$2
```

Script 1 calls the Script 2 with parameters passed as an argument. Run Script 1 using

> ./Script1.sh

and it exports the variable for script1 in first session and in the new session, it runs the script2 and initiates the other environment variables independent of the first one.

Hope this helps.